# Running Puppeteer in the Cloud and Passing It's Return to JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, puppeteer

I'm running a puppeteer script on Heroku. I've got buildpacks sorted and it's running fine. Eventually I intend to move this to my own server and run it on a 5 minute loop. My issue is that it encounters a timeout (H12 on Heroku, takes more than 30000ms to send any data back to server). Now, I've decided to try and run the puppeteer on the back-end and then return a JSON that is passed to the front-end JS and used to shape the resulting webpage.

My issue is this. I cannot use a require statement in my front-end JS as it's a caveat to node, not to "web" JS. I can't use Browserify on it as Browserify naturally doesn't support puppeteer and I can't include the puppeteer in the Express routing file as that would place the puppeteer script on the front-end which, as stated before, causes a timeout AND won't allow me to change the way the html looks.

---

### Basic Desired Function Structure:

```
Call made to localhost:PORT/puppet
Puppet script invoked
Puppet script checks if pages are up/scrapes data/does automated testing etc
Script returns a JSON which is then saved to a variable
Express serves HTML file with script and css
Script uses returned JSON to dictate page structure/style/classes
```

### File Structure:

```
puppet.js (puppeteer script)
server.js (handles routes and express)
index.html (served by server.js)
master.css
package.json
package-lock.json
```

### Node Modules:

```
colors
express
puppeteer
```

I've spent a good 4-5 days solid on this, *any and all* help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: For clarification, I need a way of passing a JSON from the server-side puppeteer script to the javascript that the html served by Express uses so I can use the values in the JSON to change the webpage.
I.E if the JSON was (a: true, b: false) then I'd give div#a the class .success and div#b the class .warn

EDIT 2: New Issue, can't use fetch on localhost. Got an api set up but can't fetch from it. Every solution garners a new problem or so it seems

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't increase the timeout for Heroku, so if you really want to trigger your puppeteer script from a request you'll need to do something like this:

1. send a 200 status
2. Get the puppeteer script running
3. Save the .JSON result in a DB (because you cannot res.send() anymore)
4. Fetch the results from the DB in your Front-End (so maybe query it every X seconds to see if your results are in.)
5. Fetch the desired HTML,CSS etc. now that you don't have to wait for the puppeteer script to end.

It's not especially elegant, but a request taking more than 30 seconds is a special case.

You could send an ID along with the 200 status code at step 1 which you can then use to query the DB at step 4.

Also, you probably know this, but you can use something like heroku-scheduler or the npm package [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to make your puppeteer script run every X minutes, but that would also imply saving the results to a DB.

Comment: That sounds excellent. I didn't know that js could interact with a database. Would it be possible to save it as a CSV or would it be better to actually use some sort of database/js interaction?

Many thanks!

Comment: Oh, good point! If you don't want to set-up a DB, you could simply save a .json or csv file on your server and delete it when it's been used. The answer to your question is do you want to keep the results for more than 24 hours? (Heroku will restart your dyno in < 24 hours)

Comment: And of course, if you want to save gigabytes of .json/csv, a database is advisable.

Comment: @Clarinetking have you considered using a docker container and spinning a db alongside your node app that way? You can create a DAL and interact with the db directly from pupeteer and call the data from a service on the front end.

Comment: Forgive me if I sound rude but that sounds like a lot of effort for extracting internal data. I'm not saying there's an easier way but is there not some way I could write a fetch polyfill that bypasses the http requirement. Either that or scrape my own api? I only say this due to my lack of database knowledge and the fact that there are only 4 fields in this JSON. Perhaps if I could pass the data directly to my index.js but my program flow is currently Express -> Puppeteer//HTML//API -> index.js(in html). Thanks for helping though, your responses are both useful and interesting!